# Installing Node Red OPC UA Server fails on Ubuntu 20.04 running on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: ubuntu, node-red, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to install the node-red-contrib-opcua-server node in Node Red running in Ubuntu 20.04 that is running on a RPi 4.
It has failed a couple of times.

I have run update/upgrade and made sure nodejs was installed.
I've tried installing this node using the command line and via the Node Red GUI.

Below is the logged information for the last install attempt.
The logged info doesn't say much to me so I'm hoping that the Linux gurus out there can shed some light on what is needed to successfully install this component.

```
2020-08-24T16:30:34.369Z Install : node-red-contrib-opcua-server 0.4.1

2020-08-24T16:30:34.445Z npm install --no-audit --no-update-notifier --no-fund --save --save-prefix="~" --production node-red-contrib-opcua-server@0.4.1 
2020-08-24T16:30:49.312Z [out]  
2020-08-24T16:30:49.312Z [out] > deasync@0.1.20 install /home/mikeallgood/.node-red/node_modules/deasync 
2020-08-24T16:30:49.312Z [out] > node ./build.js 
2020-08-24T16:30:49.312Z [out]  
2020-08-24T16:30:52.039Z [err] gyp ERR! 2020-08-24T16:30:52.042Z [err]  build error  
2020-08-24T16:30:52.042Z [err] gyp 
2020-08-24T16:30:52.044Z [err]  ERR! stack Error: not found: make 
2020-08-24T16:30:52.044Z [err] gyp ERR! stack 
2020-08-24T16:30:52.045Z [err]      at getNotFoundError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
2020-08-24T16:30:52.045Z [err] gyp ERR! stack     
 at F (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
2020-08-24T16:30:52.045Z [err] gyp ERR! stack     
 at E (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
2020-08-24T16:30:52.045Z [err] gyp ERR! stack     
 at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16 
2020-08-24T16:30:52.045Z [err] gyp ERR! stack     
 at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
2020-08-24T16:30:52.045Z [err] gyp ERR! stack     
 at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
2020-08-24T16:30:52.045Z [err] gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:168:21)
2020-08-24T16:30:52.047Z [err] gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-1015-raspi
2020-08-24T16:30:52.047Z [err] gyp ERR! 2020-08-24T16:30:52.047Z [err]  command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" 
2020-08-24T16:30:52.047Z [err] gyp ERR! cwd /home/mikeallgood/.node-red/node_modules/deasync 
2020-08-24T16:30:52.047Z [err] gyp ERR! node -v     
2020-08-24T16:30:52.048Z [err]  v12.18.3 
2020-08-24T16:30:52.048Z [err] gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0 
2020-08-24T16:30:52.048Z [err] gyp ERR! not ok  
2020-08-24T16:30:52.065Z [err] Build failed 
2020-08-24T16:30:53.421Z [err] npm 
2020-08-24T16:30:53.422Z [err]  WARN node-red-project@0.0.1 No repository field. 2020-08-24T16:30:53.464Z [err] npm 
2020-08-24T16:30:53.464Z [err]  WARN node-red-project@0.0.1 No license field. 
2020-08-24T16:30:53.465Z [err]  
2020-08-24T16:30:53.533Z [err] npm 
2020-08-24T16:30:53.533Z [err]  ERR! code ELIFECYCLE 
2020-08-24T16:30:53.533Z [err] npm ERR! errno 1 
2020-08-24T16:30:53.543Z [err] npm  
2020-08-24T16:30:53.543Z [err] ERR! deasync@0.1.20 install: `node ./build.js` 
2020-08-24T16:30:53.543Z [err] npm ERR! Exit status 1 
2020-08-24T16:30:53.543Z [err] npm ERR!
2020-08-24T16:30:53.543Z [err] npm ERR! Failed at the deasync@0.1.20 install script. 
2020-08-24T16:30:53.543Z [err] npm  
2020-08-24T16:30:53.544Z [err] ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-08-24T16:30:53.580Z [err]  
2020-08-24T16:30:53.581Z [err] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 
2020-08-24T16:30:53.581Z [err] npm ERR! 
2020-08-24T16:30:53.581Z [err]      /home/mikeallgood/.npm/_logs/2020-08-24T16_30_53_549Z-debug.log 
2020-08-24T16:30:53.638Z rc=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the basic build tools (e.g. make) required to build the native components of the npmjs modules you are trying to install.

You probably need to run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: Thanks hardillb! I'm green when it comes to Linux, which is why I'm fiddling with this project. Your help is priceless.